# usage of 'L' in colloquial cantonese utterances

Tags: meaning, cantonese

I found this in what I suspect is a very colloquial Cantonese website:
點解觀塘咁L塞

What is this 'L'? I am sure I must have seen this before, but I do not understand in what context.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [廣東粗口五大字](https://evchk.wikia.org/zh/wiki/%E5%BB%A3%E6%9D%B1%E7%B2%97%E5%8F%A3%E4%BA%94%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%97)

> 撚:

> 讀作nan2。此字乃是假借字，「撚」字是指把玩、揉搓、撥弄等的動作，在部份場合下不被視為粗口，例如「撚手小菜」即解成拿手小菜、「撚雀」則是飼養雀鳥。

> 當用作粗口時，正寫為「尸」字裡加個「粦」字，[**發音為 lan2**]，俗寫為「門」字裡加個「能」字，即是「」字。當作為粗口時，則解成下列意思：

> 名詞，「陽具」的意思 (**Noun: "penis"**)

> 語氣助詞，只用於加強語氣，用於句子中；(**Modal auxiliary words, only used to strengthen the tone and used in sentences**)

> 助詞，用作顛倒句子原本意思，可視為反語。

> 近年網民使用時，有時為避免出現粗口字，會以英文字母「L」代替。 (**In recent years, netizens sometimes use the English letter "L" instead to avoid swear words.**)

點解觀塘咁(L)塞 = 點解觀塘咁(撚)塞 = Why is Kwun Tong so (damn) congested

'塞' is short for '塞車' (be congested)-  *of traffic*

We also use:

- '小' for '屌'
- '忍' for ''
- '狗' for '㞗'
- '西' for '屄'
- '實' for '杘'

Answer (score 2):

- L =  = fucking/damn
- 咁L = why so damn/why so fucking

L is like a softening of something like the f-word, in written language, maybe akin to *frick*. But, you'll probably find it's usually spoken out in full.

---

This singer JB also has a song called:

> [點解咁撚肥](https://youtu.be/5x2YbmyP9Uk)

咁撚 can also be written = 咁L, which should probably be properly written: 咁

[Xiami](https://www.xiami.com/song/mTngvp61c6b) translates the song into English as:

> Why So Fat (Limiter)

Here though 咁l is probably better translated as:

- 咁l = so (fucking)